# Excel - Min Value in a filtered range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, conditional-formatting

So, I have a table where Date is stored in column C, and time is stored in column E.

My table runs from row 5 (though this is the headers, so data is in row 6 onwards) down to row 9989 (though this isnt too important)

Many of the rows are empty right now, but around the first 3000 are filled.

I want to apply conditional formatting which would hilight the date and time closest to the current time, which is in the future.

So, it would be finding the smallest value of Col C + Col E, where the value of Col C + Col E is > Now().

How would I put this into a conditional formatting? Many thanks.

If VBA is required, that is a plausible option, the workbook is already an .xlsm

Comment: Could you use a helper column, and base the conditional formatting off of that?

Comment: I wouldn't object to doing so, though what would I be looking to put in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add dates and times.  They are both actually numbers, which you can see if you format them as such.

Here I've added dates and times together and then performed some manipulations.

[image]

This shows the addition of dates and times and a logical test on the sum.

Now this formula returns the nearest future date:

```
=MIN(IF((A3:A11)+(B3:B11)>NOW(),(A3:A11)+(B3:B11)))
```

This is an array formula and must be entered with CTRL-Shift Enter, rather than just Enter.  If entered correctly, Excel surrounds the formula with curly brackets {} in the formula bar.

I couldn't get the conditional formatting dialog to accept an array formula, but there's an easy workaround.

The array formula is entered in F3 (this cell can be located somewhere else or hidden). And the conditional formatting rule refers to the result in that cell:

[image]

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: I can do that, but what I want is only the date / time which is closest to the current time, but > Now() to be hilighted. EG if its currently midday, and I have 3 rows, each with todays date adn the times at 11am, 1pm and 2pm, I would want just the 1pm row to be hilighted, but your example would hilight both 1pm and 2pm.

Comment: See my edit.  I think this does what you want.